# Bar path in hack deadlift

Tags: deadlifts

In conventional deadlift, I've read that bar path is supposed to be straight up. In the variation with the bar behind the back, however, I think it can only be done with a slight horizontal motion as the bar goes up. Have a look at this video by [strong first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXmv4crntw8) for example.

Why is this?